# Android base64 encoded string invalid?

Tags: android, base64

I have problems decoding a Base64 encoded image.
For example i got the following string from the server:

```
data:image\/jpg; base64,\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD\/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQ
sJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz\/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA
wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz\/wAARCABFAOIDASIAAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIE
AwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZW
mNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8v
P09fb3+Pn6\/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiM
oEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkp
OUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6\/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD5rooor8
DP9oAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooA9f8ADPhrTp\/Dmnu+n2
Tu9tGzM0CksSoyScVe\/wCEU0v\/AKBth\/4Dp\/hR4U\/5FbTf+vWL\/wBAFX6\/1HyHIcsllmGlLD023Th9iP8AKvI\/5YOPuPuJ6fE+Y06
eY10lXrJJVqlklUloveKH\/CKaX\/0DbD\/wHT\/Cj\/hFNL\/6Bth\/4Dp\/hV+vpT9pf9i7w\/8AC39nTwx4x8M6jrV\/qJsdMuvEltePE0
doL+38yGWIIqssfmJInzFjnHPBJ0xuEyPC1aVGth4J1HZfu42v56aXdkvNpHl5XxLxrmFGvWwuY12qMeeX7+pflW9lza2Sbfkm+h8uf8Ippf8
A0DbD\/wAB0\/wo\/wCEU0v\/AKBth\/4Dp\/hX0z+yL+x5oPxp+GPiLxJ4r1DWNPVUurfw\/BYPGjXtxbWkl1M8nmI2YUVY1O3ndJjIryf4e
\/AHxT8UNDl1PS7Kyj0yO6SwF7qWqWumW0tyylhBHJcyRrJLtGSiEsAQSACM5wpcPyq1aTo017Kyk3CKV5bWbVns166bm1TO+O4YbD4pY7EyV
fn5FGtVcrQtzNxUrrRprutdjz7\/AIRTS\/8AoG2H\/gOn+FH\/AAiml\/8AQNsP\/AdP8K9N8MfsveP\/ABj4t8QaDp3hm\/n1nwqvmarZMy
RzWi7wm4qzAsMsOVz8vzfd5qj41+AvijwB\/Yz6hY2klt4hdo9OvLDUrbULO7dX2Mi3FvI8W9WwCpbIyCQARXTHA5BKapRp0XJ9LQvqrrT019
NTjnxRx1ClKtPF4tQjdNupWsmnytN3srPR9npucB\/wiml\/9A2w\/wDAdP8ACj\/hFNL\/AOgbYf8AgOn+FehQfs9+L7n4tX\/gZNIz4p0z7
R9psvtUP7ryI2ll\/eb\/ACztRGPDHOMDJ4rjK2pZRktX+HQpPRPSMHo9nts7Oz620OavxrxlQv7fH4qNpSjrVqr3o25o6y+KN1zLdXV90UP+
EU0v\/oG2H\/gOn+FH\/CKaX\/0DbD\/wHT\/CvqvwZ+w9ofi79pfwT4QXUr2PRdd8LWWu6jJLqlnb3iyz2TzlbdZFHmKJFHyqjsqZLHA3Dxj
Tv2fPFGteM5NBsINJ1O9t7N9RuJrHW7G6sbO3QEvLNdxzNbxKuOTJIuCVB5YZ83Dx4drScY0qStFTd4wXutyXb+679lbuexi8349w8I1JY7Ey
UpOC5a1V3klB20l151bu7roed\/8ACKaX\/wBA2w\/8B0\/wo\/4RTS\/+gbYf+A6f4V6Pqn7OHjLSPG3h7w\/JpUUuoeLWjXRmtr+2ubTUi7
+WvlXMcjQN8\/ykh\/lPXFa0n7GvxLW2uWj8LzXU9jcRWt7ZWt3b3N\/p7yFhH9otY5GngVtpw0iKpGDnBGemWF4dik5Qoq+2kNdbafPT10OS
HEfHs3KMMVjG47+\/W005tddPd19NdjyL\/hFNL\/6Bth\/4Dp\/hR\/wiml\/9A2w\/8B0\/wrufiL8FPEfwr0\/TbzV7S0\/s\/WA5sr6w1
C21GzuSjbXVZ7eSSMup6ru3DIyORXK11UcmyatD2lKhSku6jBrTTou5wYnjfjDDVPZYjMMTCWmjq1U9dVo5dVqih\/wiml\/9A2w\/8B0\/wo
\/4RTS\/+gbYf+A6f4Vforb\/AFfyv\/oGp\/8AgEf8jn\/4iFxV\/wBDPEf+Dqn\/AMkUP+EU0v8A6Bth\/wCA6f4VR8TeGtOg8Oag6afZI6
W0jKywKCpCnBBxW7VDxX\/yK2pf9esv\/oBryc+yHLI5ZiJRw1NNU5\/Yj\/K\/I+t4B4+4nqcT5bTqZjXadeimnWqNNe0jo\/ePEqKKK\/y4
P+p8KKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAPbfCn\/Irab\/ANesX\/oAq\/VDwp\/yK2m\/9esX\/oAq\/X+rnD\/\/ACK8N\/17h\/6Sj\/kz8Qv+SpzP
\/sIrf+nJBX3VqviazuPj54K8B6zMsWg\/E\/4U6N4fnaQ4SG6aAtaTfVZwgH++etfCtFRnGTRx\/LzS5eVSW3V2tJa7xaTXmcvDnEk8oc5U4
czk4PV6WjK7i1bVTV4vbRs+4vCGoWvg\/wDabt\/hhpNylzpPwx8Da1p000X+rvNRkspZb2Yf9tW2c8gRAdq4jw\/EfiT+xj8PLTwt8OtJ+Jm
o+FL7U7fXLD\/iZS3umSXEwlgm8iyuIXMckakeYyuoMW0FSCD8qUV5ceFeVxnGr7y5XezV5L2nNJ8sk\/f9rJ2TVnbdaHvT49UozovDr2cudJ
XT5YSVBQiuaEl+7VCKu4vmTekXqfYHhHx\/4h+IF3+0XqHibT9L0bXY\/AkVlc2emyForfymt4ghJlkbzAqhXDOWDBlYBgQOA0TUo9J\/YK8M
Xk+TFY\/E55SQMlVFjCzY\/wC+f0FfP1FdVLhyFN+7Ky5oOyW3JHlstXv87ba7nBiOMZ1o2nBt8tWN3JXftXe7tFK8fJK\/lsfemgfCDXD\/A
MFE\/GXjd7ZIPCep2Wq3+l6rLIEtdaS402UxLaOeJ32uXKoTtVHJxjn40sdX8Ex+CzBc+H\/FMviLyXUX0XiGCOyEhJ2N9mNkz7QNuV8\/LYO
GXPHLUVeWZDLDP97U5rQpwVrw0p81r2k735tVtpsTnnFkccm6FHkcqtarLmcaibrezuknBcqj7NWer137\/bWg6pbaR\/wUF+B8l3cQWsUngj
SbdXmkCKZJdKkjjXJ4yzuqj1LAVw37L\/g\/UfBXgP4veAtZ8GJc+PNZsNPutM8Oa7Hd2U2rw29w0s8cSxyQyu2zEiojgyeXwGAIr5eorl\/1
YfsnTVX7NNbPenUlUi9JJ2vKzW9tpJnYuOI+1jVlQvyyqP4la1WlCjNNODTfLBOLtZN6xkj6u8AeKPFlt8efgP4U8QeAtK+H2naR4rjvNN06N
LuK9\/fXMPmPJHd3Es6xsy\/ISFViH2ltrYzfhDqdz\/wlX7Tz\/aJ98\/hrVWkbzDmQnUYQST3yGYH\/AHj618x0VrLhuMotc6V0k9Hv7Tnb
1k3r1u99fIwp8aShOEvZtqMlJXkloqfs1H3YRVlurJWWlup71raA\/wDBM\/QWwNw+Il2AccgHT4s\/yH5V4LRRXs4HB\/VlNXvzSlL0v0Pm8
zzL64qK5eX2cIw3ve19dlbfbX1Ciiiu48sKoeK\/+RW1L\/r1l\/8AQDV+qHiv\/kVtS\/69Zf8A0A15HEH\/ACK8T\/17n\/6Sz7Dw9\/5Kr
LP+wij\/AOnIniVFFFf5RH\/WYFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAHb6V8Yv7M0u2tv7O3\/AGeJYt32jG7aAM42+1T\/APC8f+oZ\/wCTP\/2NcDRX
6vh\/G\/jahSjQpY20YpJL2dHZaL\/l2fyZmH0GvBHHYqrjcVknNUqSlKT+s4tXlJtt2WISV29kkux33\/C8f+oZ\/wCTP\/2NH\/C8f+oZ\/
wCTP\/2NcDRW3\/Ed+Of+g7\/ylR\/+VnH\/AMSFeBP\/AEIv\/LrGf\/NB33\/C8f8AqGf+TP8A9jR\/wvH\/AKhn\/kz\/APY1wNFH\/Ed+
Of8AoO\/8pUf\/AJWH\/EhXgT\/0Iv8Ay6xn\/wA0Hff8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY0f8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY1wNFH\/Ed+Of+g7\/AMpUf\/lYf8S
FeBP\/AEIv\/LrGf\/NB33\/C8f8AqGf+TP8A9jR\/wvH\/AKhn\/kz\/APY1wNFH\/Ed+Of8AoO\/8pUf\/AJWH\/EhXgT\/0Iv8Ay6xn\/w
A0Hff8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY0f8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY1wNFH\/Ed+Of+g7\/AMpUf\/lYf8SFeBP\/AEIv\/LrGf\/NB33\/C8f8AqGf+TP8A9j
R\/wvH\/AKhn\/kz\/APY1wNFH\/Ed+Of8AoO\/8pUf\/AJWH\/EhXgT\/0Iv8Ay6xn\/wA0Hff8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY0f8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8
AY1wNFH\/Ed+Of+g7\/AMpUf\/lYf8SFeBP\/AEIv\/LrGf\/NB33\/C8f8AqGf+TP8A9jR\/wvH\/AKhn\/kz\/APY1wNFH\/Ed+Of8AoO\/
8pUf\/AJWH\/EhXgT\/0Iv8Ay6xn\/wA0Hff8Lx\/6hn\/kz\/8AY1Bqvxi\/tPS7m2\/s7Z9oiaLd9ozt3AjONvvXEUVliPHDjavSlRq428Z
Jpr2dHZ6P\/l2dmX\/Qa8EcDiqWNwuSctSnKM4v6zi3aUWmnZ4hp2a2aa7hRRRX5Of1mFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRR
QAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB\/9k=
```

The [Online Tool](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/) i found here decodes that String correctly but the code 
i used here:

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

Produces an error:

```
02-02 19:16:56.460: E/AndroidRuntime(18237): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

So where is the problem? I guess if it wouldnt be a valid Base64 encoded string the online tool in the link i provided also wouldnt be able to decode it.

**EDIT**

found another [Online Tool](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) it is telling:

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

But it's not telling where. I deleted the padding '=' but it did not change.

Comment: Are you sure that your are encoding the image properly? Because your decoding technique is correct. Now the image data is the only part where there can be an issue

Comment: i updated my post. another online tool says that it is not valid.

Comment: can you post the code of your encoding of your image. I believe that will help us resolve the issue. Plus are you trying to download the image or view the image on your mobile, from web??

Comment: The encoding is the PHP base64 encoding method. i get this string inside a json from the server to my mobile device.

Comment: ok deleting the meta-data did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know this is the correct solution for this, But in my case I removed the starting part up to `data:image\/jpg; base64,` from the above response and it worked for me. This is the data which not the part of encoded data.